# Express middleware lose res.locals after I post form

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I have an Express app and this have option to switch theme and I implement this with a global middleware:

```
app.get('*', (req, res, next) => {
    req.session.theme = req.query.theme || req.session.theme || 'light';
    res.locals.theme = req.session.theme;
    next();
});

app.use('/contact', require('./routes/contact.route'));
```

The **theme** it is available in all views, but I have two views with contact form and after I submit this form the ***theme is unavailable***

I used like this in ejs contact.ejs and header.ejs :

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="<%=captcha%>" data-theme="<%= theme %>"></div>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/theme-<%=theme%>.css" type="text/css" />
```

And the problem it is caused by the executing middleware, this middleware it is not executed after I submit the form **app.get('*'** ...

This is because app.get('*') middleware it is executed just for GET requests?

Thank you!

Comment: Since you are posting the form have you tried changing`app.get('*',/* rest */)` with `app.post('*',/* rest */)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your form is sending the post or put request, which it should be, your `app.get()` is not executing in the form submission.

Just change your code to this

```
app.use( (req, res, next) => {
    req.session.theme = req.query.theme || req.session.theme || 'light';
    res.locals.theme = req.session.theme;
    next();
});
```

I hope that will fix the issue, if it doesn't please let me know.